# Cron job is not working in Godaddy cPanel?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am using `Godaddy cPanel` and I want to **run** `crone_page.php` page **once a day**. And in this page I have added PHP email code and PDO insert query. I have created cron job using below command with common setting 0(M) 0(H)*(D)*(M)*(W).

```html
 php /home/user_name/public_html/folder_name/crone_page.php
```

Every day I am getting email, but data is not saving in my database. It means insert query is not working here. But if I run this page manually, then both are working - I mean email as well as insert query.

So, do I need to make any changes in my cPanel settings?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: its cron not crone

Comment: ok. Any suggestion pls?

Comment: without the code, i dont see how you expect any one to help you

Comment: I have written only email and insert query code. Do you want me to show this code?

Comment: try : php -q /home/user_name/public_html/folder_name/crone_page.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup following cron in your account and check this again.

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/user_name/public_html/folder_name/crone_page.php
```